# Why is a "link-only" post deleted rather than giving the opportunity to add more detail?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, link-only-answers, vote-to-undelete

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Is .NET Core == .Net Framework 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955459/is-net-core-net-framework-5/56009570#56009570)

The reason for deleting my answer was: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."

This seems fair enough, but why is it deleted straight away rather than giving a chance to improve the answer? I discovered that I can still edit it but if I vote to undelete it I'm told that a moderator has deleted it and it can't be undeleted.

Is there a way to flag it for possible review and undeletion?

Comment: When you have edited your post to fix the issue(s) mentioned, you can always custom flag the post for a moderator to review (there should be a flag link above the deletion notice)

Comment: Thanks Samuel, didn't realise I could do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This seems fair enough, but why is it deleted straight away rather than giving a chance to improve the answer?

Because it is not a valid answer to the question, according to [Stack Overflow's standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). That is independently sufficient grounds to delete the answer.

Furthermore, as you've observed, it is still possible for you to edit the answer while it is deleted. All deletion here is "soft" deletion. In other words, deleted content is only hidden from public view. The original poster of the content, as well as [users with moderation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), can always see deleted content. Therefore, deleting an answer effectively *hides* it from public view, while still allowing the original poster to edit it to bring it into compliance with our guidelines.

We don't want to wait around until those edits are made because, statistically speaking, they almost never are. If you *do* decide to make those edits, you can always flag the post for moderator attention and ask for us to reconsider its deletion. If you have, in fact, brought it into compliance with our guidelines, we will happily undelete it. In fact, flags like this are quite encouraging to see. It always brightens my day just a bit to see that someone took our advice to improve their content and thus the site as a whole.

I've undeleted the answer in response to your flag (which I actually saw and handled before I saw this Meta question).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and for undeleting it. Much appreciated! :)